# Не могу изменить цвет кнопки через кастомный xml файл

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

создал кастомный xml файл, где указал оранжевый цвет, и немного скруглил углы, после создания кнопки указал в качестве бекграунда созданный xml файл, но цвет кнопки остался прежним, в чем может быть дело ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы на эмуляторе пробовали запускать? проблема может быть в отображении через редактор

Comment: Здравствуйте, пробовал, на эмуляторе так же без изменений

Comment: Цвета обычно хранят в colors.xml и от туда вызывают, а не картинками Drawable

Comment: Попробуйте указать ширину и высоты в Shape

Comment: Картинки в код переделайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорей всего у вас стоит Material тема и поэтому все Button превращаются в [MaterialButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton)

В документации написано, что для MaterialButton лучше не использовать `android:background`:

> All attributes from R.styleable.MaterialButton are supported. Do not use the android:background attribute. MaterialButton manages its own background drawable, and setting a new background means MaterialButton can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it introduces will function properly. If the default background is changed, MaterialButton cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

Если вы хотите изменить радиус углов, то используйте `app:cornerRadius`, а для цвета `app:backgroundTint`

```
<Button
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="#FFCE14"
    app:cornerRadius="10dp" />
```

Comment: Где это использовать ? в Button нельзя указать app:cornerRadius

Comment: @DmitriyUsov можно, просто нужно добавить  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` в корневой лаяут

Comment: Ааа так у меня есть эта строчка

Comment: тогда не понимаю в чём проблема

Comment: Вы можете попробовать сделать так же, интересно у вас будет тот же эффект или нет

Comment: У меня всё работает. Eсли IDE не показывает подсказку, это не значит, что их нельзя добавить

Comment: у меня есть строчка xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" в constraint layout Но я все равно не могу писать в теле Button app:backgroundTint или cornerRadius

Comment: @DmitriyUsov что значит не можете? просто напечатайте руками, пример добавил в ответ

Comment: Все получилось )  В файлах в папке res/values/themes нужно в теге style параметр name с materialcomponents сменил на appcompact, после всё заработало

Comment: Ну это настолько же верное решение, насколько верно забивать гвозди микроскопом